# Render all content and action urls as absolute urls without changing the viewpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I want to render all urls in a view as absolute urls if the request referrer has a different origin than the request itslef.

So if site `http://www.hostsite.com` has a page that pulls content from `http://www.example.com/controller/action` then the following viewpage

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", new AjaxOptions {}))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("More..", "More")
    <img src="~/Content/img.jpg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

should render as

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/controller/Save" data-ajax="true" id="form0" method="post">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/controller/More">More...</a>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/Content/img.jpg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Note the usage of "~/" urls in html should also be fix to absolute.

If at all possible I would like to achieve this by overriding some base url generating code, instead of creating extra helpers.

Is it possible to override the url output functionality of mvc and not have to change a single detail in the viewpages themselves(like using custom helpers)? If so, where are the hooking points that I can use to override this output behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Actionlink method as below

```
public static HtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
                                        ,string linkText,string action,string controller)
    {           
        return new HtmlString(String.Format("<a href=http://www.example.com/{0}/{1}>{2}</a>", controller, action,linkText));
    }
```

This will return the desired URL you want.

**Uses in View**

```
 @Html.CustomActionLink("DemoLink","Index","Home")
```

This will generate desired output

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/Home/Index">DemoLink</a>
```

[DemoLink](http://www.example.com/Home/Index)

Similarly you can create helper method for other overloads of ActionResult and for images as well.

Comment: I specifically do not want to create 'helper' methods. I want to override behaviour of the ViewEngine and its associated classes like ViewPage.

Comment: The view engine is responsible for rendering the views, we can override the path of views, We can change the Physical location of views i.e. we can place the views in virtual file location e.g on Database server or even in DLLs instead of physical file storage. But the behaviour you are trying to achieve is something which is not the responsibility of view engine. How controls will be rendered and what HTML will be generated for controls, is handled and managed by helper classes. So have to override the same.

Comment: `<img src="~/Content/img.jpg" />` is not rendered by helpers